# Mongodb Error when export database and collection

Tags: database, mongodb, export

When I am trying to export the MongoDb database with command line with below command

```
mongodump -d mydb -o /var/www/html/
```

I am getting below error

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:5
```

while I have tried many commands but the error is same. What could be a possible reason?

Please let me know.

Comment: You should be running mongodump from the system command line, not your mongo shell, please revert back otherwise.

Comment: @Yasasvee,thanks,this is working now.I was trying in Mongodb shell.

Answer (score 2):

You should be running `mongodump` from the system command line, not your mongo shell.